# Uniqueness of codimension one embedding of a lattice of square-free determinant into the standard lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, bilinear-form, integer-lattices

This question is a continuation of my previous question: [Uniqueness of codimension one embedding into the standard lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829608/uniqueness-of-codimension-one-embedding-into-the-standard-lattice).

Let $L$ be a positive-definite lattice of rank $n$, and suppose $L$ embeds into the standard lattice $\Bbb Z^{n+1}$. Is it true that the embedding is determined unique up to the following sense?

1. First, if $i:L\to \Bbb Z^{n+1}$ is an embedding of lattices, and if $f:\Bbb Z^{n+1}\to \Bbb Z^{n+1}$ is an automorphism, then $f\circ i$ is also an embedding. We regard $i$ and $f\circ i$ equivalent.
2. In the case that $L$ is decomposable, for example if $L=L_1\oplus L_2$, $g:L_1\to L_1$ is an automorphism and $i:X\to \Bbb Z^{n+1}$ is an embedding then $L=L_1\oplus L_2\xrightarrow{g\oplus \textrm{id}}L_1\oplus L_2=L\xrightarrow{i}\Bbb Z^{n+1}$ is a new embedding. We regard these two are equivalent.

For example, the lattice $(\Bbb Z,\langle 5\rangle)$ embeds into $\Bbb Z^2$ by $1\mapsto 2e_1+e_2$, and this is unique up to automorphism of $\Bbb Z^2$. (If the codimension is $>1$ then of course we do not have uniqueness.)

In the previous question that I linked, it is shown in the answer that such embedding is not unique, but a counterexample given has non-square-free determinant. Is the above question true if $\det L$ is square-free (so that $i(L)\subset \Bbb Z^{n+1}$ is a primitive lattice)?

Comment: As I said in the comments of the question you linked, your result is true for $n=1$
 if $L$ has square free determinant $D$.
Indeed, In this case, then $D=u^2+v^2$, where $u,v$
 are coprime. But $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$
 acts transitively on the set of vectors with coprime coordinates (this is because a column vector with coprime coordinates may be completed in an invertible matrix , using a Bézout relation. I don't know for larger $n$ yet.